# How to load imageViews in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have ViewPager in my app that contains 7 fragments and each fragment contains several images.
I want to display ProgressBar while each fragment load it's images.
So I created AsyncTask that loads the images in the background. 
The problem is that I can't load the images with Picasso library it shows me some errors.
Can someone help me to figure how to do it?

**EDIT:** The reason I ask this is because it takes about 1.5 second to load all the images with Picasso and it looks very laggy. with "android:src" the app crashes sometime because OutOfMemory issue, "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." So I'm looking for a better way.

Thank you!!!

fragment1.java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);

    LoadImagesTask loadImagesTask = new LoadImagesTask();
    loadImagesTask.execute();

                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
}

private class LoadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P6);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P7);
        ImageView image8 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P8);
        ImageView image9 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P9);
        ImageView image10 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P10);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p1).into(image1);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p2).into(image2);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p3).into(image3);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p4).into(image4);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p5).into(image5);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p6).into(image6);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p7).into(image7);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p8).into(image8);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p9).into(image9);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.s0p10).into(image10);
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void event) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-12 17:03:32.838 17497-17581/appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                                     Process: appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube, PID: 17497
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.
                                                                                         at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain(Utils.java:136)
                                                                                         at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:615)
                                                                                         at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                                                         at appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube.Intro$LoadImagesTask.doInBackground(Intro.java:68)
                                                                                         at appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube.Intro$LoadImagesTask.doInBackground(Intro.java:36)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You don't need an async task for this.  These images are local and you can call the Picaso....load(img).into(img) from the main thread directly.

Comment: @FishStix I know that but it takes about 1.5 second to load all the images and it looks very laggy

Comment: Downloading assets from the web will always take time.  If your assets are local, as it looks like they may be, R.drawable.s0p1, why can't you set the "src" attribute in the layout xml?  Downloading images via a URL will typically take 1.5 seconds, and thus things like loaders and fade-ins should be used.

Comment: @FishStix You're basically right but in my case the app crashes because OutOfMemory issue

Comment: How big are these images?  Regardless of critiquing your code... there may be other issues at play.

Comment: @FishStix Each one is about 80 KB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117145/discussion-between-fishstix-and-itiel-maimon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind AsyncTask is that doInBackground does the background work, then you can return something that will be passed as a parameter to onPostExecute which is executed in the main thread.
So try to set image from onPostExecute() method :)
But you can easily do this without using AsyncTask, just do like this:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    private ImageView imv1;
    private ImageView imv2;
    private ImageView imv3;
    private ImageView imv4;
    private ImageView imv5;
    private ImageView imv6;
    private ImageView imv7;
    private ImageView imv8;
    private ImageView imv9;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        imv1 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imv2 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imv3 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imv4 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imv5 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imv6 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imv7 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imv8 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        imv9 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    }

    private void setImage() {
        // show progress dialog
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // set your images here.
            }
        });
        // dismiss progressDialog here
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask usullay use for networking or process which take a long time to be done..I think you don't need to use AsyncTask in this situation. :) Just write in a method and call it.

Comment: I use this because it takes about 1.5 second to load all the images and it looks very laggy

Comment: Do you know another way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You can try to use handler :) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Just show a progress dialog to the user while images are processing would make your app smoother

Comment: Just edit my answer. 
above is a simple way to do this (like what you did), just use a simple thread with progress dialog, then call the method in onActivityCreated() or anywhere you want.

Comment: Where should I initialize my ProgressBar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a good answer you should post here some more code.

Generally speaking, you can simply use the drawable as a "android:src" inside the ImageView xml entity (your doing pretty much the same here only using the programmatic approach here...)
Or use Picasso on the Main\UI thread (it's the same name for the thread that has a sole responsibility of rendering the UI componenets), i.e. on the inflate method.

And generally speaking try and inspect some more tutorials of 'how to' using fragments and general android design patterns, you're obviously still learning but using googles recomeneded methods will ease your learning and minimze your bugs.

Comment: I'm not a beginner. I know how to do what you mentioned but it takes about 1.5 second to load all the images with Picasso and it looks very laggy. with "android:src" the app crashes sometime because OutOfMemory issue, "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. "So I'm looking for better way.